# JNLP only starting when Java console is shown?

Tags: java, jnlp

I have Java version 8 Update 261 on a 64 bit Windows 10 system.

What I did:

- downloaded and executed a `jnlp` file
- the application was installed in the Java cache and a desktop icon was created
- the application was starting

So far, so good.
Now, after closing the app and double clicking that desktop icon - nothing happens.
However, in the Task-Manager I see that the Java Web Launcher is running. And every further double click starts another instance of it, but on the screen I see nothing.

To get the application running properly again, I can either

- clear the Java cache with hook at "installed applications and applets" set:
  [image]

  The desktop icon is removed, the above procedure can then be repeated and works like a charm.
- or show the Java console
  [image]
  In this case double clicking the desktop icon works! The Java console opens and after some seconds the application is starting.
  There's no need to clear the cache anymore.

I understand that clearing the cache can solve manifold issues, but what effect has the simple "show console" here?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question ... but I'd like to point out that JNLP supported in Java 9, and removed in Java 11.  So the application you are using is on borrowed time ... unless you switch to a 3rd-party implementation of Java Web Start.

Comment: The only still supported version of Webstart I know of is https://openwebstart.com/.